# using sscanf to read string with spaces from char[]

Tags: c

I have a string and i want to split it in to variables for example:

```
char[]="i 176064 Patterson";
```

i want by using sscanf to have:

```
firstword = "i"
secondword = 176064
thirdword = "Patterson"
```

but secondword must be a int.

how is that possible?

EDIT:

i have write this code:

```
int main()
{   char cstr[] = "i 176064 Patterson Denise 8.58 11 DEN 15788 ";
    string option,name,sername,dep;
    int studID,numofc,post;
    float gpa;
    sscanf(cstr, "%s %d %s %s %2.2f %d %s %d",option,&studID,name,sername,&gpa,&numofc,dep,&post);

}
```

but i get a compiler error

> error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘std::string {aka class std::basic_string}’ through ‘...’|

any ideas?

Comment: `nb_read = sscanf(yourstring,"%s%d%s",firstword,&secondword,thirdword);`

Comment: The error message indicates you're using a C++ compiler to compile what you think is C code (judging from the tag on the question).  At least one of you is confused!

Comment: maybe you really should [edit] your question to specify C++ or drop the `string` part.

Comment: If you are using C, define a MAX_LEN and Change "string option,name,sername,dep;" to "char option[MAX_LEN], name[MAX_LEN], sername[MAX_LEN], dep[MAX_LEN];".